# RewriteRule matching parent folder on internal redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all the single blog page urls to a PHP template.

/blog/blog-post-1 would say route to the index.php of /blog/ but keep the url the existing slug to pull in the data.

A basic router really just for the blog folder.

However the parent folder /blog/ also seems to be getting matched. I only want to the single/children pages to match.

I've tried several htaccess RewriteRules and tested them on a regex checker site and also a htaccess matcher site.

The internal code redirect below actually seems to work on those sites but on my localhost it is matching the parent page as well.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ / [L,NC]
```

This matches the parent page as well (/blog/) and it also goes back to the home page.

However if I carry it out as an actual Redirect

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ / [R,L,NC]
```

It works as expected and only works on the children. The only issue is that it removes the existing url.

I expected the first redirect to work and only redirect the children pages but it actually matches everything.

Adding a R flag and making it an actual redirect seems to work.

Not sure if i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After turning on the mod_rewrite log I found that apache2 is cycling through the possible urls for that path.

So it would check:

blog/
blog/index.html
blog/index.php

The last one being the actual path which also matches the htaccess rule.

I updated the rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ / [L,NC]
```

To make sure the requested url isn't a file or a directory already.

Seems to do the job. I'm sure there's other Cond rules that might help.